# ALB is not getting created for Ingress

Tags: amazon-eks

I have EKS 1.17 running on AWS. I'm trying to create an Ingress resource with ALB but unable to create it due to the following error.

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/main/docs/examples/2048/2048_full.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "vingress.elbv2.k8s.aws": Post https://aws-load-balancer-webhook-service.kube-system.svc:443/validate-networking-v1beta1-ingress?timeout=10s: no endpoints available for service "aws-load-balancer-webhook-service"
```

ALB controller is deployed

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-47-151 ~]$ kubectl -n kube-system rollout status deployment aws-load-balancer-controller

deployment "aws-load-balancer-controller" successfully rolled out
```

Comment: Have you deployed the [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html)?

Comment: Yes @BastianKlein

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue when trying to deploy an Ingress.

Turned out my Node Group was too small and the pods were not scheduled.

Be sure to check that your pods are actually running with:
`kubectl -n kube-system get pods`
[image]

You can also 'describe' the pod to see what issues you might be having:
`kubectl -n kube-system describe pod aws-load-balancer-controller-769589b5c7-fn6j7` (as an example)
[image]